# Image dissapears with "ResourceMeta - Resource not found"

Tags: grails, resources, grails-2.0

In my Grails 2.2.4 project I'm having `ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /images/passenger.gif`.

The problem is, that just after deployment the resource is accessible, but on day 2 or 3 it "expires", although it's still present under tomcat/webapps/ROOT/images.

In my gsp I'm using it like that:

`<img src="${g.resource( dir:'images', file:'passenger.png' )}"/>`

Comment: Your error says: Resource not found: /images/passenger.gif but you mention image as .png in <img> src. I think , it may be cause any trouble to you.                                                                           
And what "expires" means here? I am not getting what it means?

Comment: then it's even worse! there's no passenger.gif image nor it's used anywhere. Only .png exists and referenced. "expires" means in my case, that it disappears after some time after deployment

Comment: I've had this problem hosting grails app on certain host like heroku and uhurucloud. If you are sure its not your code, I'll trying hosting it elsewhere or running grails prod run-app to see if that's the problem.

Comment: the app is indeed deployed on amazons ec2 instance. For now I got rid of resources-plugin dependency. Will see if it fixes the issue